# \equiv with dots on the bottom

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I was looking for a `\equiv` symbol, but with dots on the bottom, on each side of it. I looked up on [the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and couldn't find it.

I tried to write `.\equiv .`, but didn't like the result and, unfortunately, I don't know exactly what the symbol stands for, my guess is something topology related.

Below, I leave an image on what the symbol look like, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you actually seen this "in the wild"?  If so, can you give a citation?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I can't, I just have the symbol. Basically, a friend of mine sent me a message asking if I knew how to write it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you want a relation symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dottedequiv}{\mathrel{.{\equiv}.}}

\begin{document}

$X\dottedequiv Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The braces around `\equiv` make it into an ordinary symbol, so TeX doesn't add space around it, but it will around the whole construction that's declared `\mathrel`.